# Is any difference between "command1 & command2 &" vs "command1 & command2"?

Tags: shell, unix, command-line-arguments

I know "&" operator between commands mean the commands are executed concurrently. However, what does "&" do in the "`command1 & command 2 &`" ?

Answer (score 5):

```
ps1%>  command1 & command2
```

In this example, command1 runs from the background, while command2 runs from foreground. You don't get command prompt until command 2 finishes.

```
ps1%>  command1 & command2 &
```

In this second example, both command1 and command2 run from background, immediately yielding command prompt to you, while both are running.

To test and feel it, you can do this:

```
ps1%> sleep 10 & sleep 4
[1] 8134
```

In this example, you will see PID ( process id ) of the background command, while 'sleep 4' command is running in the foreground.

```
ps1%> sleep 10 & sleep 4 &
[1] 8139
[2] 8140
```

In this second example, will show two of them, representing two running in background, while you get back to prompt immediately.

Comment: Jay, please, show which command line is first and which is second.

Answer (score 2):

`&` is not a binary operator (between two commands), it is a unary postfix operator, i.e. one coming after a command, and instructing the shell to run the specified command in the background. When `&` comes between two commands, it is allowed to omit the normal `;` separator, i.e. to write `foo&; bar` as `foo & bar`. This usage makes `&` look like a binary operator.

Thus, `command1 & command2` is in fact equivalent to `command1& ; command2`, and means "run command1 in the background, then run command2 and wait for command2 to finish". `command1 & command2 &` is equivalent to  `command1& ; command2&`, and means "run both command1 and command2 in the background, and immediately resume execution of the script (or return to the prompt, if interactive)".

Since at least one command is in the background, the two commands are in fact executed "in parallel" in both cases.